# jQuery $get() - compare loaded data with each()

Tags: jquery, get, compare, each

I have two lists .album and .favorites

First I was using this `each()` loop to compare the .album items against the .favorites
When there is a favorite copy in the .album list I append a favorite icon.

```
$(".album li").each(function(index) {
    var itemSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    if ( $(".favorites li img[src*='" + itemSrc + "']").length > 0 ) {
        $(this).append('<span class="favorite"><\/span>');
    }
});
```

Now I switched to an approach where I load the favorites in later, so I need to use `$get()` to compare the loaded data with my .album items

```
$.get("ajax-load-favorites.php", {}, function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    $(".album li").each(function(index) {
        var itemSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        /* compare with data here */
    });
});
```

ajax-load-favorites.php returns this:

```
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/album/tn/006.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/album/tn/003.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/album/tn/010.jpg" /></li>
```

Comment: what is the problem in above code you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple string search would solve your problem:

```
$.get("ajax-load-favorites.php", {}, function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    $(".album li").each(function(index) {
        var itemSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        if (data.indexOf(itemSrc) != -1) {
            $(this).append('<span class="favorite"><\/span>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("ajax-load-favorites.php", {}, function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    $("li", data).each(function(index) {
        var itemSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        if ( $(".favorites li img[src*='" + itemSrc + "']").length > 0 ) {
           $(this).append('<span class="favorite"><\/span>');
        }
    });
});
```

It's basically the same, just modify the selector to search in your ajax-loaded data.

Comment: But I don't have the <ul> element in my data... only the list items